# Confused about this C code I saw in a job interview

Tags: c, linked-list

**Disclaimer:** *I'm allowed to talk about the interview question since I already was rejected by the company and never had to sign an NDA before taking the interview test anyhow.*

Also, this isn't a "Write my code for me" post. I'm just curious about understanding the setup of this problem. It wanted me to fill in the body of a function that removes an element from a linked list:

```
typedef struct
{
    int val;
    node * next;
} node;

void remove_val(node ** arr, int i)
{
    /* Write the procedure here */
}
```

I was confused about why the problem had a pointer-to-a-pointer as a parameter. I would expect that the parameter to a function would be the root of the list, which would be a pointer to a node. Right? Any idea what the first parameter was supposed to be???

Comment: How would you remove the first element of the list?

Comment: How would you remove the single element of a linked list with 1 element?

Comment: @undur_gongor: Change the second element to be the root; destroy the first element.

Comment: ... and then your head pointer points to nowhere because you did not change it.

Comment: Consider a list of zero, one, two, or more items. The value might be anywhere

Comment: How would you change the second element to be the root if you are simply passed `node *root`?

Comment: Pointers, like everything else in C, are passed by *value*. Yes, you can use that value (an address) via dereference to modify what it *points to*, but what if the thing you need to modify is itself a pointer (such as a pointer to the head of some list)? Then the solution is to pass the address of *that* pointer (and declare the formal parameter to be a pointer-to-pointer)

Comment: The question itself has an error; node* next is not a defined type.

Comment: No wonder I failed the interview. lol! They had several options of programming languages I could take the interview in, and I should've chose Java or C++. Ain't no one got time for pointers.

Comment: Removing the first node with a plain pointer is easy enough here since you can just do `node->val = node->next->val; node->next = node->next->next; free(node->next);` but as @pmg indicates this just replaces the problem with one of removing the last node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you remove the head of the list?  You need some way to communicate that back to the calling code.  This function signature allows you to change the head of the list to point to its `next`, if necessary.